# java .matches() does not match

Tags: java, regex

I have a following piece of code:

```
String myString;
boolean myResult;

myString = "First\nSecond\nThird\nFourth";
myResult = myString.matches("First.*");
myResult = myString.matches(".*First.*");
myResult = myString.matches(".*Second.*");
myResult = myString.matches("First\nSecond\nThird\nFourth");
```

the last one returns true, all the rest are false...

I though all of the above expressions would return true. Also I need to find strings that start with "First", I thought the first .matches() would cover it, but it does not. How should it look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot doesn't by default match end-of-line chars, but if you prefix your regex string with (?s), then it **will** match them. This enables the [DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) match flag.

Answer (score 2):

.*    probably doesnt match \n

replace one \n from your last match pattern with . and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> . Any character (may or may not match line terminators)

Answer (score 1):

you can try to specify the \n\r literally:

```
myResult = myString.matches("First(.|[\n\r])*")
```